# I could not understand why "javac: file not found: HelloWorld.java"

Tags: java

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

Following error message  keeps coming out every time when I run in cmd

> javac: file not found: HelloWorld.java

However, when I added my file location

```
javac D:\User\Documents\Project\HelloWorld.java
```

It runs successfully.
Why?

I have tried to edit variable value of `PATH` to `D:\User\Documents\Project`

But it did not work.

Comment: Cd into the dir

Comment: you are not in the D directory so it will show this message

Comment: Change your directory before using javac command. Go to your Project Directory by using cd command in cmd  D: cd User\Documents\Project  and after that use javac HelloWorld.java

Comment: The javac command will not search for you where `HelloWorld.java` could be located. Besides, you could have multiple classes with this name. The very most of command line programs work in this way.  At last you should also not use the default package that is not recommended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have never used the command prompt before. The command prompt has a "current directory", just like in a file explorer window, there is a "current directory", the directory that you are viewing right now.

The current directory is usually shown just to the left of the caret.

[image]

The current directory on the above photo is `C:\Users\Mrhope`.

Type `dir` to see all the files and directories of the current directory. You can then use `cd` to navigate to a subdirectory. Say you are in `Documents` now, and you can do this

```
cd Project
```

to go to the `Project` folder. By the way `../` means the parent directory

The `HelloWorld.java` in `javac HelloWorld.java` is a path relative to the current directory, so this will only work if HelloWorld.java is in the current directory. You should try to use `cd` to navigate to the correct directory then use that command.

Setting the `PATH` environmental variable is quite irrelevant here because that is setting the path of the JRE. Please set it back.

I suggest you learn the basics of `cmd` first. Many tutorials are available online.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation ><

Comment: @tingweijingting If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter the directory of where your Java file is. 
Fastest way is to open the folder where your Jar file is then hold the shift key on your PC and right click on an empty space in the folder (while still holding the shift key). When the context menu comes up look for the **open command window here** option (for newer Windows 10 versions it's power shell window), select the appropriate option. When it opens run your command

[image]