# I am having trouble using command prompt for java program execution

Tags: java

Can anyone tell me that why when I'm providing the whole path after typing like **"javac C:\Java\MyFirstApp.java"** then it is compiling. But when I directly go for **"javac MyFirstApp.java"** it is showing me file not found.

Comment: Are you in ``C:\Java``? Are you sure? Does `type MyFirstApp.java` work?

Comment: What is your current working directory?

Comment: for 'type MyFirstApp.java' I am getting the error **The system cannot find the file specified.**

Comment: what is ur current path where u are typing this command to run java file

Comment: C:\ Java is my current working directory.

Comment: Duplicate (I'm out of votes): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48335415/i-could-not-understand-why-javac-file-not-found-helloworld-java

Comment: Oh I got it now! Thanks. That path was wrong. I changed it to C:\Java. I was in C:\users before. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not in same directory where .java is placed. Change directory to app folder using cd command and type only javac MyfirstApp.java

Comment: And can you tell me just how to do that. I'm new in all this and I have no idea!

Comment: Go to cmd and type cd C:\Java

Comment: then type javac MyFirstApplication.java

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember, to execute the program you don't need to inform the extension.

Go to your project's folder and try:

```
javac Main.java
java Main
```

Comment: It is giving me `file not found`.